# Amend previous commit with no change to commit message

Tags: git, github, git-amend

I had already pushed some changes to a remote. Now I need to push some other changes which should be in that previously pushed commit but somehow are not. I can do this simply by pushing the changes with a new commit but just now I have found the `--no-edit` flag and `--amend`

If I need to push the new changes but I need a single commit having the old and new changes is `git commit --amend --no-edit` going to achieve that?

Comment: What happened when you used it?

Comment: Short answer is yes, but make sure rewriting history is okay in your context, and don't forget to add your new changes before amending.

Comment: Not an answer, but: when you have pushed something already, consider just pushing a new commit, unless *you are sure nobody else hasn't checked out the same branch*.

Comment: Also, just leave the `--no-edit` out until you are very comfortable with `--amend`. Seeing the commit message in editor is one extra chance for you to verify you are amending the right commit.

Comment: @RomainValeri 
Thank you so much for your tip to don't forget to add the new changes before amending.

This is exactly what I am missing.

Comment: @hyde Thank you for all tips. Yes, I am sure nobody else hasn't checked out the same branch.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, the `git commit --amend --no-edit` is the thing that I am looking for.

1. `git add .`  (*Add the added and modified files*)
2. `git commit --amend --no-edit`
3. `git push --force-with-lease <remote> <branch>`

Answer (score 3):

Generally, it's best to avoid rewriting the history, and just add a new commit as hyde suggested.

If you really need to overwrite the history, make sure to use `--force-with-lease` when you push.